# Google Maps 404 Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization

I'm using google chart maps however, when I try to draw the map, it logs several errors of 404 to their server. however, I'm pretty sure i'm using the API correctly. The only information relating to this I could find was when people were using the old undocumented API at maps.google.com, which doesn't happen on their tutorial page. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? 
Code and console below for reference:
[image: Google maps error]

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['map'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGoogleMap);

function drawGoogleMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Lat', 'Long'],
    [21.3117, -157.8]
  ]);

  var options = {
    enableScrollWheel: true,
    useMapTypeControl: true
  };

  var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById("main"));

  map.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['map']}]}"></script>

<div id="main" class="chart_div container">
 

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong.

The issue: the API tries to draw all the markers inside the viewport.
To be able to achieve it, the API calculates the zoomlevel.
With a single marker as in your example it will use the maximum zoom(seems to be 22, note the z-parameter in the broken URLs).
When the API loads a tile it didn't check if a tile exists(so it may happen that the request returns a 404, it happens very often)

Later the API requests the ViewPortService(you'll also see the request in the network-tab). This request returns informations about available data for the given ViewPort,  especially available tiles(e.g. satellite-images).

After this request you will see further requests to URLs similar to the broken URLs, but with a different z-parameter(e.g. 20). It means: the ViewPortService has detected that for the given ViewPort satellite-images only be available for zoom 20, so the zoom of the map will be set to 20 and now the tiles may be loaded.

Just ignore the 404s

Comment: It looks like they'll need to fix that, maybe i'll submit a ticket, but in the meantime, thanks! was pounding my head about that and couldn't figure out how to prevent that error from coming up.

Comment: well, it seems to be weird to serve 1.5kb for an error-document instead of a transparent png with status 200 when a tile didn't exist, but I can't imagine that there isn't a reason for it.

Comment: well i mean they should default to their absolute maximum listed as 19 instead of trying to force to 22

Comment: That wouldn't fix it, because there are places in the world where no satellite-images are available for zoom 19

Comment: fair enough, thaks again